# Increase Logo size on sticky menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

I have a website and I would like to increase the logo size when the menu becomes sticky.
(when scrolling down, the logo in the white menu)
The link to the website is: [website](https://www.atvmototraveler.ro/) and for PasteBin - link to source code: [link](https://pastebin.com/NMvG66nm).

Source code:

```html
<header class="banner navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top  headhesive--clone headhesive--stick" role="banner" data-transparent-header="true">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div id="logo">
        <a href="https://www.atvmototraveler.ro/">
          <img data-rjs="2" class="logo-trans logo-reg" src="https://www.atvmototraveler.ro/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/atv_de_inchiriat_inchirieri_atv_inchirieri_motociclete_cluj_cluj_napoca_atvmototraveler-61x61.png" alt="Atvmototraveler" width="61" height="61">
          <img data-rjs="2" class="logo-main logo-reg" src="https://www.atvmototraveler.ro/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/inchirieri_atv-inchiriat_inchirieri_atv_cluj_inchiriere_atv_de_inchiriat_rent_atv_cluj_logo-1-301x300.png" alt="Atvmototraveler" width="61" height="61">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="themo_cart_icon">
      <a href="https://www.atvmototraveler.ro/cart/">
        <i class="th-icon th-i-cart3"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation" style="height: 0px;">
      <ul id="menu-atv-de-inchiriat-meniu" class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-312 current_page_item menu-item-447">
          <a href="https://www.atvmototraveler.ro/" aria-current="page">
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Închirieri ATV </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1245">
          <a href="https://www.atvmototraveler.ro/trasee/">
            <i class="fas fa-map-signs"></i> Trasee </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1207">
          <a href="https://www.atvmototraveler.ro/flota/">
            <i class="fas fa-truck-monster"></i> Flota </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1645">
          <a href="https://www.atvmototraveler.ro/despre-noi/">
            <i class="far fa-building"></i>&nbsp;Despre Noi </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-724">
          <a href="https://www.atvmototraveler.ro/contact/">
            <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Contact </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-557">
          <a href="https://www.atvmototraveler.ro/product/inchirieaza-atv-cluj/">
            <i class="fas fa-key"></i> Rezervă Acum </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Thanks

Comment: You already know how to create a snippet. Can you include any CSS/JS required for this HTML? We need the full picture. Also, if you're including your code here in a snippet, then there' s no reason to include a pastebin link as well.

Comment: `.headhesive--clone.headhesive--stick #logo img { height: 60px !important }` you can change the `60px` to whatever, but your app.css is adding `!important` so you will too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this css.

```
.headhesive--clone.headhesive--stick div#logo .logo-main {
    height: 82px !important;
    max-height: unset !important;
}
```